# Fechar side nav ao realizar a função de rolar a pagina

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3, materialize

```js
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/252168/edit#
```

```css
section{
height:100vh;
width:100vw;

}
#a{
background-color:black;
}
#b{
background-color:red;
}
#c{
background-color:green;
}
#d{
background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
      <!--Import materialize.css-->
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>
 <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">

  <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
      <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    </head>

    <body>
     <nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
      <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
      <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li><a class="scroll" href="#1">Sass</a></li>
        <li><a class="scroll" href="#2">Components</a></li>
        <li><a class="scroll" href="#3">Javascript</a></li>
        <li><a class="scroll" href="#4">Mobile</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
        <li><a class="scroll" href="#a">Sass</a></li>
        <li><a class="scroll" href="#b">Components</a></li>
        <li><a class="scroll" href="#c">Javascript</a></li>
        <li><a class="scroll" href="#d">Mobile</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
    <section id="a"></section>
    <section id="b"></section>
    <section id="c"></section>
    <section id="d"></section>
    
      <!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
      <script type"text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.button-collapse').sideNav();
  $('.scroll').click(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     var id = $(this).attr('href');
     targetOffset = $(id).offset().top;
     menuHeight = $('.scroll').innerHeight();
     $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:targetOffset - menuHeight}, 500)
   });
  });
      </script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Tenho a função de rolar a pagina ao clicar em um link que esta dentro do meu menu, quando estou no mobile ele me apresenta aquele menu lateral e dentro dele há os links citados acima, ao clicar ele rola até a secção indicada pelo id, porém eu queria que ao clicar ele fechasse esse menu lateral, para que o usuário não tivesse que fechar. Estou usando o Framework materialize CSS para apresentar o menu lateral. PS: não consegui fazer o código rodar aqui no stack.

Comment: Poste o codigo, sem ele fica dificil ajudar

Comment: postei da uma olhada ai

Comment: Seria legal um funcional para simular o erro, consegue?

Comment: coloca no teu pc que ele funciona e aparece o erro